# Разбор выражения на три переменные регулярным выражением

Tags: python

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, разбирающее на три переменные входные данные типа:

```
1A 2b 33c    
22С 20 12B
```

Должно получится:

- Входные данные: 25A 35 4
- Получается 3 переменные:

  a=25A,
  b=35,
  c=4

Comment: Извените опечатался, исправил

Comment: Точно исправили? Как из 35 получить 20?

Comment: Господа, это ассиметричная квантовая криптография.

Comment: @rnd_d Откуда `(\d)` вытащит все числа? И что положить взамен?

В задании есть и такое: `a=25A`

Comment: @alexlz , мне стыдно, плохо читал странные условия. выпяливаюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если второе число будет не 35, а 40, то чему будет равно b?

А если серьёзно, то может регулярки и не надо?

```
  text = "25A 35 4"
  [a, b, c] = text.split()
```